# How to parallelize a function involving multiple arguments in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a function,

```
def Recommendation(df1,df2,array1,array2):
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        . #do something
        . 
        .
        result = {} #The result is a dictionary and is inserted into mongodb
        db.collectionname.insert_one(result)
```

df1 data is large and it takes lot of time to complete the execution in a loop. How do I parallelize this process in python using multiple arguments?

```
   def parallelize_dataframe(df,func):
       df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)    
       pool = Pool(num_cores)
       pool.starmap(func,df_split)
       pool.close()
       pool.join()

   num_partitions = 5
   num_cores = 5


  if __name__ == '__main__':
       df1= pd.read_csv("filename.csv")    
       df2= pd.read_csv("filename2.csv")

       array1 = numpy.array1 #Loading numpy array
       array2 = numpy.array2 

       parallelize_dataframe(df1, Recommendation)
```

This process is very slow. I am not sure if the work is distributed across the cores. Kindly help.

Comment: why declaring `parallelize_dataframe` twice?

Comment: dont't call Recommendation when you give it as an argument to parallelize_dataframe, this waits to get a result form Recommendation(), you want to pass just Recommendation

Comment: Have a look at functools.partial

Comment: @Marc i tried but it gets into infinite execution.

Comment: Did you remove the loop in Recommendation? Could you update the question with what you tried?